# illustrator... removing part of stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I added white stroke to a shape, but would like to remove part of the stroke. Specifically, I'd like to remove the circled portion of stroke. What's the best way to achieve this?  I tried scissor tool but didn't work.  Thx in advance

Comment: No best way since you havent defined anything as a metric for best. Anyway: Expand stroke and edit, round corner or adjust miter limit. To be honest though i would just split this into 2 separate closed paths, not that this situation would ever come up in my work.

Comment: Thanks but I'm new to IL and I'm not being sure what all this exactly means... mind elaborating a lil bit?

Comment: I'm trying to envision the underlying path which results in these two corners -- seems like it may be a path which loops upon itself. Seeing the *actual* path would help.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this in my experience: with your object selected, Open up the **Stroke Panel**, locate the **Corner** option, select **"Round Join"** the middle option. That should solve your issue while keeping the stroke editable.

[image: Stroke Panel]

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the actual path would be best if you want us to help you. However, I'll try giving you a quick answer.

Option 1:
If you want to remove that part, and the outline to remain an outline:
Select the object, grab the pen tool, then click with it exactly at the two points where the center of the outline meets your pink circle. That should create two new anchor points on the outline (= the points that define where the line goes through). Then select and delete the anchor points within the pink circle, which are what most probably creates the white angles. You might need to click on the two anchor points you created earlier to reconnect them.

Option 2:
If you don't mind the outline turning into a shape, select the outline, go to the top menu, and click object -> expand. Then create a new shape ontop of the part that you want to cut. Select both the new shape and what was your outline, and then go to the pathfinder window to subtract top from bottom.